# How to store each rendered frame as image in libgdx for debugging

Tags: libgdx, rendering, debugging

I have a libgdx screen's render method where I am executing lots of for loops and drawing various shapes on screen in thoese loops. Also I am manupulating (x,y) of each shape at runtime to acheive a smooth animation.Everything was ok until,

**Issue:** Recently I had added few more shape's at some positions in my screen. Due to some mess up, I am getting flicker, and some shapes are getting drawn out of my game world.

I tried to debug my code many times but there are too many loops and shapes so I am unable ***to pin point the exact loop or frame*** where shapes are getting drawn out of my game world.

**Need Input on following approach to debug:**

So I was thinking **to save each frame of my render method as an image locally. Is it possible?** Please provide suggestions or sample code to acheive it.

I will hook up some debug variables in my loops to calculate exact frame where things are getting messed up. That I will take care of.  Please advice on above question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is absolutly possible. Here's a simple class that, when called, will save a screenshot of the main graphical context:

```
public class ScreenshotFactory {

    private static int counter = 1;
    public static void saveScreenshot(){
        try{
            FileHandle fh;
            do{
                fh = new FileHandle("screenshot" + counter++ + ".png");
            }while (fh.exists());
            Pixmap pixmap = getScreenshot(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);
            PixmapIO.writePNG(fh, pixmap);
            pixmap.dispose();
        }catch (Exception e){           
        }
    }

    private static Pixmap getScreenshot(int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean yDown){
        final Pixmap pixmap = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(x, y, w, h);

        if (yDown) {
            // Flip the pixmap upside down
            ByteBuffer pixels = pixmap.getPixels();
            int numBytes = w * h * 4;
            byte[] lines = new byte[numBytes];
            int numBytesPerLine = w * 4;
            for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
                pixels.position((h - i - 1) * numBytesPerLine);
                pixels.get(lines, i * numBytesPerLine, numBytesPerLine);
            }
            pixels.clear();
            pixels.put(lines);
        }

        return pixmap;
    }
}
```

The only thing you have to do if you have this class in your project is to call the following line in each of your *render* loop:

```
ScreenshotFactory.saveScreenshot();
```

It will save the screenshot as *screenshotX.png*, *X* being the smallest number available, starting with 1.

Just make sure you draw the frame number or an identifier on the image to be able to match it with all your debug messages.

#### Source

- Shamelessly taken from [libGDX's Github Wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Take-a-Screenshot).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this and get back to you in case of any doubt.

Comment: @kingAm If you don't have any problems with this code and it answered your question, feel free to accept it using the gray checkmark below the up and down vote arrows.

Comment: I know that, i will try this code first and award you, don't worry.Thanks again. :D

Comment: @kingAm My bad, I tought you had plenty of time yesterday to test it, and you didn't come back with any feedback...